# How to lazy-load a component from another git repository(used as an npm module)?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, react-loadable

I have a git repository which I am importing as a npm module in my package.json file. Now I am trying to load this component using react-loadable, but my bundle.js size does not seem to reduce. Although I can see a chunk getting created, but it does not contain my component's code in it. It is still present in the main bundle.js file. Can anyone mention if lazy-loading is supported for another git repositories used as npm module?

Comment: Please add your code to better understand the problem..  or please go for https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy for further details

Comment: i feel like its more a `webpack` question